# What should we point duplicates of "how to upgrade while skipping in-between releases" to?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I've noticed that there seem to be a lot of questions which basically ask, "how can I upgrade my Ubuntu installation directly from version *x* to version *z*, skipping version(s) *y* in between?"

There appears to be a tendency for people to post a different question for each possible pair of versions, when in reality they all would have the same [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/45669/18612). I was slightly surprised to not be able to find a "master" question for all these in a search.

Here's a partial list of such questions for reference:

- [Skipping intermediate Ubuntu OS upgrade to latest one,How do I upgrade from 9.04 to 10.04.2?](https://askubuntu.com/q/47807/18612)
- [Can I upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92119/18612)
- [How to upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/65707/18612)
- [Is it possible to skip releases during an upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/q/45666/18612)
- [Can I upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04 using iso image](https://askubuntu.com/q/46712/18612)

Should one of these questions be modified to a more general one which we can then point all the duplicates to? Is there already a "master" question that I simply missed? Or would a new generalized post be best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Is it possible to skip releases during an upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45666/is-it-possible-to-skip-releases-during-an-upgrade) should likely be the canonical question for questions of these types.

Comment: It should now likely be [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/how-do-i-upgrade-straight-from-a-very-old-release-to-the-latest-one) instead, considering that one you have there was recently closed as a duplicate of it.